# I need add date in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've got a problem to add dates in Laravel. I've got a query:

```
$days_off = DaysOff::latest()->get()->where('user_id', $employee->id);
```

and that query working fine. Show me rows which a need but in the last column a need add dates, how many days someone was on holiday. In my view I've got something like:

```
@foreach($days_off as $day_off)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $day_off->off_type }}</td>
        <td>{{ $day_off->off_from }}</td>
        <td>{{ $day_off->off_to }}</td>
        <td> I need sum off_from and off_to over here  </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Maybe some one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Carbon library that comes by default installed with laravel.

```
 //call the namespace at the top
use Carbon\Carbon; 

//start date
$offFrom = Carbon::parse($days_off->off_from);

//end date
$offTo = Carbon::parse($days_off->off_to);

diffInDays()
```

it's a carbon function to calculate difference between two given dates. You can use that to get total days off like so:

```
$TotalDaysOff = $offTo->diffInDays($offFrom);
```

then you can pass `$TotalDaysOff` to the view;

You can also do that in the view itself;

```
@foreach($days_off as $day_off)

        <tr>
            <td>{{ $day_off->off_type }}</td>
            <td>{{ $start = $day_off->off_from }}</td>
            <td>{{ $end = $day_off->off_to }}</td>
            <td> {{$end->diffInDays(start)}} days off  </td>
        </tr>

        @endforeach
```

Comment: First problem when I wanna debug this
//start date
        $offFrom = Carbon::parse($days_off->off_from);

//end date
        $offTo = Carbon::parse($days_off->off_to);

        return dd($offFrom) ;

(1/1) Exception
Property [off_from] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: make sure off_from exists in the model, and make sure you don't have any misspelling on it